# How do I create a server to client connection on a non-http protocol using Java?

Tags: java, php, database, http, tunnel

I have two java applications (a client and a server). The server application and the database are on the same server. However, the client application could be anywhere. My problem is that the server blocks all connections (except http), so I cannot access my database with my client application, is it possible to use something like a tunnel via HTTP(or ftp) to make my client application able to ask my database?

Comment: Yes. It is. What have you tried/researched to achieve this?

Comment: Why does the client have to talk to the database directly? Server queries database locally and gives data to client over HTTP.

Comment: Yes, i have found some solutions like REST but i would like to know if there are others solutions(eventually less complexe)

Comment: @MarcellFülöp it's what i would like to do, but i don't know at all how to do this.

Comment: @user3745832 Easiest and most secure solution is to query the server for the data and have the server hit the DB.  If you have a client talk directly with the database it is a huge vulnerability.

Comment: @Zoop the server cannot answer the client because my host does not accept extern connection. The only way client have to ask something on my server is via http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Sockets. It's low level compared to modern frameworks, but you can connect to a specific port and send data packets easily from client to server.

You will need to create a Server Socket and listen to connections on port 80 (HTTP).

The client will have it's own Client Socket and connect to the server socket at that port, and begin sending data, which can be from raw bytes to whole serialized objects.

You then handle these packages from the Server, and, if needed, send a response to the client.

[All About Sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/)

***PS: You may also want to take a look at Java Threading for handling multiple clients. Please note, that without Thread support, you'd only be able to have one connected client at a time***

Comment: I was already using sockets but I tought that if I used port 80 it would make interference . Is it safe to use socket on port 80? Will it not make interference between http and java?Java(serv) will not be overload by analysing everything on port:80? :/

Comment: If it's not being used, it's safe to use. Just make sure you don't have any web server running

Comment: thank you, I will try it now and tell you if it works :D

Comment: So, actually it does not work, I will try on this way

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, what problems did you encounter?

Comment: On linux it does not accept to use port <1050 and as I don't have root I cannot change it,however I made it works by using another server.